# Have in C++ analog ContainsKey (TKey) from C# - what is best practics?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

Have in C++ analog IDictionary.ContainsKey (TKey) or List.Contains (T) from C# ?

For example I have array of elements and need to know have this array some value or not ?
What is best way or best practics - without "foreach" for each element !
It will be good if it's will from std library for example.

**UPD 1**: In std lib have many containers, but I want to find a best way - faster, little code, less complicated and so on ...

Lookind that **better desigion** is `std::unordered_set` if going on [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

```
    #include <unordered_set>

    std::unordered_set<std::string> NamesOfValues = { 
    "one", 
    "two", 
    "Date",
    "Time" 
    };

  // and now check is value exists in set
  if(NamesOfValues.count(value))
    {
        // value exists
    }
```

Comment: Could take a look at std::map (in particular - find() function): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Comment: May be, I have take a look - but may be have better desigion - for example std::map::count look even better...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if map contains a value for a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136520/determine-if-map-contains-a-value-for-a-key)

Comment: @underscore_d- I know that for example std lib have many containers for values like map, set and so on - I ask about better desigion and  best practics for do it !

Comment: May be you can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136520/determine-if-map-contains-a-value-for-a-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems most concise to use `count`, and this should work for any container.

```
if ( my_map.count(key) ) { // shorthand for `count(key) != 0`
    // It exists
} else {
    // It does not
}
```

If we're talking about `[unordered_]map` and `[unordered_]set`, which are closest to your original dictionary type, then these containers enforce unique keys, so the returned `.count()` can only be `0` or `1`, and there's no need to worry about the code pointlessly iterating the rest of the container once it finds a match (as would occur for containers supporting duplicates)

Either way, simply using implicit conversion to `bool` leads to the most concise code. And if you end up having a design that might allow/need different counts per key, then you could compare against a specific value.

Comment: May be better if (my_map.count(key) > 0) ?

Comment: I don't see why. Neither `map` nor `set` can contain more than 1 element of a given key. So the result will either be 0 or 1. Why complicate things? But if you prefer the semantics of writing `> 0`, then sure, feel free. I guess it might make the code more easily transferable to another type of container later.

Comment: @Alexander I updated it simply to implicitly convert the returned count to `bool`, which looks even more concise.

Comment: Excuse me - what is your opinion - what is beter choise in map, set , unordered_map and unordered_set ? If I don't worry about order inside array ?

Comment: Isn't it simple? If you don't care about order, then use the unordered version, so you won't be paying for forced ordering that you don't care about. If you only need a key, then don't use a map, which also has a value that you don't care about. More generally, consult [In which scenario do I use a particular STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

Comment: You're welcome! Enjoy C++ and the many options in the Standard Library. :D

Answer (score 2):

Your are looking for [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).  Find looks for an arbitrary type input to an arbitrary iterable and returns an iterator to that element.

For example, to find an element in a dictionary you can do the following:

```
std::unordered_map<char,int> my_map = { {'a', 1},{'b', 2}};

auto found_element = std::find(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), 'a');
if( found_element == my_map.end() ){
   //nothing was found
}
else{
   // do something
}
```

For standard map you also have `map.find(T)` for O(1) access instead of O(n).

```
if( my_map.find('a') != my_map.end() ){
   //something was found!
}
else{
   //nothing was found
}
```

This is more clear than `my_map.count()`... you would only use that if you were actually trying to figure out how many elements you have and if you were using non unique keys.

Comment: @Alexander what do you mean by "big code", also i included an example now.   There's no other standard way to do this as far as I know

Comment: @Alexander you could wrap code like this in a boolean function and then just pass the parameters through. That way you could have something like .containsKey(...) return true or false

Comment: @Alexander  That doesn't make much sense if you are using unordered maps... it also would take the same amount of space, I'll edit my post to show it.